# Call recursion method java

Tags: java

I have defined a recursion method (at least I believe it is recursive) that returns void and want to call it in another method, but don't know how. I know it's very basic, but can someone please help? Thanks.

Recursive method:

```
private static void recursiveWhiteToBlack(BufferedImage image, int width, int height){
    image.getRaster().setPixel(width,height, new int [] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});        
    int[][] neighbors = neighborsXY(width,height);

    for(int i = 0; i<neighbors.length; i++){
        int neighborX = neighbors[i][0];
        int neighborY = neighbors[i][1];
        int[] neighborColor = image.getRaster().getPixel(neighborX, neighborY, new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});

        if(neighborColor[0] == 1){
            recursiveWhiteToBlack(image, neighborX, neighborY);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Calling it:

```
public static BufferedImage countObjects(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage original, ComponentPanel panel){
      BufferedImage target = copyImage(image);

      for(int width=1; width<image.getRaster().getWidth()-1; width++){ //Determine the dimensions for the width (x)         

          for(int height=1; height<image.getRaster().getHeight()-1; height++){ //Determine the dimensions for the height (y)

              int[] pixel = image.getRaster().getPixel(width, height, new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});

              if(pixel[0] == 1){                      
                   none = recursiveWhitetoBlack(image, width, height);  //HOW TO CALL IT HERE!!!//

              }

      System.out.println("countObjects method called");
        return target;

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code shows that you've called it.

Answer (score 0):

You call it like this:

```
if(pixel[0] == 1){                      
     recursiveWhitetoBlack(image, width, height);
}
```

since the method has no return type, there is no need for variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `none =` since your method returns void (actually means it does not return anything)

So this should look like :

```
if(pixel[0] == 1){                      
    recursiveWhitetoBlack(image, width, height);  

}
```

also note that `none` is not defined as a variable/member so it is invalid to use it.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? will be helpful if you post it in your question as well

Answer (score 0):

This could be trouble. I'm not sure you have a true stopping condition.  You'll know right away when you get an out of memory error.